# How the JDBC Connection Pooling helps here

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have a web application. I have implemented REST Web services using Jersey into it. So my controller is Jersey ServletContainer servlet, and that is packaged inside the jar. 
Now let suppose i have n number of customers connecting to my app and fetching data from DB through API endpoints. 
I want to have a global connection pool from where my every customer can get a connection and i would be able to reduce my connection creation overhead. 
So, i thought of putting it into the **init()** or **contextInitialized()** method of controller servlet, but i can't do that as the jersey controller is already packaged inside the jersey jar as a class file. So i have implemeneted it by code by creating a static block inside a GenericConnection class that takes care of creating the context and data source so that i don't create the context also everytime.

```
public class GenericConnection {
    static DataSource dataSource;
    Connection con;

    static {
        try{
            System.out.println("1 and thats all");
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/moodoff_notificationRead_DB");
        }
        catch(Exception ee){
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // Get a connection from the connection pool
    public Connection getNewConnection(){
        try {
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

But i am not sure of the fact that whether for every user request it would create a global pool and can share connection from there.
I intentionally created a static block and put everything inside that so that it gets initialized only once.
Will it really help me achieve what i want to? And if there is any other tuning that i can do into it.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes, it would help. But your code is not thread safe. Connection should be a **local** variable of getNewConnection(). And I don't really see why `getNewConnection()` is not static. And you shouldn't catch and ignore exceptions.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks!! By synchronizing you want to tell me to make the static code part threadsafe? what i see is only after i fire the first GET request this static block is executes as line gets printed in console, does it mean that my connection pool gets created only when i fire the first request or during server startup?

Comment: A static block is executed when the class containing it is initialized. If the class is never used before the first request, then it's normal to see this code run at the first request. I never said anything about synchronizing. I said that your code wasn't thread-safe, becuase the `con` variable is an instance variable rather than being a local variable of the getNewConnection() method.

Comment: @JBNizet : But that does not create any problem, right, because every user is going to get a separate connection as for every user a separate instance of con would get created, though i can save some memory by making the method static and directly returning datasource.getConnection() from the method. Am i correct?

Comment: It depends if you share the instance between threads. As soon as you do that, you have a potential thread-safety problem. But even if you never do that why would you NOT make the variable local? What's the point of making it an instance variable? There is no reason to make the scope larger than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running in a container, chances are that you are already using a connection pool. Just make sure that's setup correctly with a reasonable max number of connections (and that your DB can support that number).

You should not be writing your own pooling mechanism, even outside of a container.